# I am trying to simplify this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can this code be simplified? I am pretty sure it can be achieved by abstracting the variable and using an if else or a switch, each case would be the element ID...I'm having a a difficult time working through this.

```
        function NoTime() {
            if (shortTime == "") {
                timeFormat = "N/A"
            }
        }

        var shortTime;
        var day;
        var month;
        var year;

        var revisionDate = document.getElementById("RevisionDate").value;
        shortTime = revisionDate;
        day = revisionDate.substring(8, 10);
        month = revisionDate.substring(4, 7);
        year = revisionDate.substring(11, 15);
        var timeFormat = day + " " + month + " " + year;
        NoTime();
        $("#RevisionDate")
            .replaceWith("<div id='RevisionDate' class='col-md-12 margin-bottom-10px pad-L-15px border-1px width-174px pad-LR-3px width-227px' /></div>");
        $("#RevisionDate").html(timeFormat);

        var supplierPartInformationEffectiveDate = document.getElementById("SupplierPartInformationEffectiveDate")
            .value;
        shortTime = supplierPartInformationEffectiveDate;
        day = supplierPartInformationEffectiveDate.substring(8, 10);
        month = supplierPartInformationEffectiveDate.substring(4, 7);
        year = supplierPartInformationEffectiveDate.substring(11, 15);
        var timeFormat = day + " " + month + " " + year;
        NoTime();
        $("#SupplierPartInformationEffectiveDate")
            .replaceWith("<div id='SupplierPartInformationEffectiveDate' class='col-md-12 margin-bottom-10px pad-LR-3px border-1px pad-LR-3px width-342px' /></div>");
        $("#SupplierPartInformationEffectiveDate").html(timeFormat);

        var SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate = document.getElementById("SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate")
            .value;
        shortTime = SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate;
        day = SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate.substring(8, 10);
        month = SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate.substring(4, 7);
        year = SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate.substring(11, 15);
        var timeFormat = day + " " + month + " " + year;
        NoTime();
        $("#SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate")
            .replaceWith("<div id='SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate' class='col-md-12 margin-bottom-10px pad-LR-3px border-1px pad-LR-3px width-342px' /></div>");
        $("#SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate").html(timeFormat);
```

Comment: it perhaps could be simplified even more by using momentjs for working with time and date.

Comment: Simplify, I don't know. But use `Date` object to handle dates is the priority. Substring to dates is ugly

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: However, this question seems to be perfect to post in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of stackoverflow

Comment: you could move the repeated parts into a function.

Comment: I have posted this in both, in the hopes of more meaningful replies, this however has not produced any thing that can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var idArray = [ RevisionDate, SupplierPartInformationEffectiveDate, SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate ];
        var attrIDArray = ["RevisionDate", "SupplierPartInformationEffectiveDate", "SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate"];
        var stringIDArray = ["#RevisionDate", "#SupplierPartInformationEffectiveDate", "#SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate"];

        for (i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
            var value = document.getElementById(attrIDArray[i]).value;

            var day = value.substring(8, 10);
            var month = value.substring(4, 7);
            var year = value.substring(11, 15);

            var timeFormat = day + " " + month + " " + year;

            if (value == "") {
                timeFormat = "N/A";
            }

            $(stringIDArray[i]).replaceWith("<div id='" + attrIDArray[i] + "' class='col-md-12 margin-bottom-10px pad-L-15px border-1px pad-LR-3px pad-TB-2px darkgrey-border-1px' /></div>");

            if (stringIDArray[i] === "#RevisionDate") {
                $("#RevisionDate").css("width", "227px");
            } else {
                $("#SupplierPartInformationEffectiveDate").css("width", "342px");
                $("#SupplierPartInformationExpirationDate").css("width", "342px");
            }

            $(stringIDArray[i]).html(timeFormat);
        }
```

Comment: This is what I was going for, but apparently I misjudged my own refactoring skills.